# MyBatis after generate greater than symbol

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I have MyBatis `v=3.4.5` and plugin MyBatis Generator `v=1.3.7` for Eclipse IDE.
After i run generate in my .xml mappers all symbols `> <` was changed see image
[image]

I found that it was normal for xml mappers but why it was happened and how to fix this symbols ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your question is but in XML some characters cannot be placed in a CDATA section (the text you see in the body of the tags).

For example, to include a `<` it must be encoded as the "XML entity" `&lt;`. Otherwise it could be confused for a tag. Other characters also need to be encoded. Therefore:

- `<` must be encoded as `&lt;`.
- `&` must be encoded as `&amp;`.
- `>` can be encoded as `&gt;`. **This is your case**.
- `'` (single quote) can be encoded as `&apos;`.
- `"` (double quote) can be encoded as `&quot;`.

This is expected since `<` and `&` are illegal in plain form in the body tags.